# Pre-loading pages with a `UIPageViewController`, including on the first page turn

Tags: ios, uipageviewcontroller

When swiping between pages, a `UIPageViewController` nicely makes sure the next/previous content pages are loaded and ready to go. This is great, but there's a catch: it never does this on the first page turn after a call to `setViewControllers` (see below). I suspect this may be an efficiency saving where it's reasoned a common case is where a user never swipes. Either way, I'm not taking this as a bug.

So I can (almost) resign to a noticeable delay on the first page turn. After this, everything should be smooth.  However my problem is that in one scenario I often make further calls to `setViewControllers` dynamically depending on user input, and so in this case pre-loading is effectively broken.

What I would like is an API to tell `UIPageViewController` to always pre-load neighbouring pages - I know a user will always swipe. Failing that, my best workaround is this:

```
let page = getContentPage()
myPageViewController.setViewControllers([page], direction: .forward,
                                        animated: true, completion: nil)

// Here we must manually pre-load 
let nextPage = pageViewController(myPageViewController, viewControllerAfter: page)
nextPage?.loadViewIfNeeded()     // 1.                           
nextPage?.view.layoutIfNeeded()  // 2.
```

This half-works: I now get pre-loading of the view (1.) which saves noticeable time.

My problem is Auto Layout.  It's evident that `UIPageViewController`'s pre-loading also nicely handles layout in advance, whereas my manual approach still has a perceptible delay immediately on a page turn.  Adding `layoutIfNeeded` in (2.) does indeed prompt a layout but I still observe a further call on the page turn regardless (to be clear: this only happens for my manual approach on an as-yet unseen page).  Worse, when I call (2.) pages don't layout correctly - e.g. `UILabel`s don't properly wrap their text content.

How can I either effectively emulate or prompt a `UIPageViewController` to always pre-load neighbouring pages, including on the first page turn?

Comment: Where are you putting `nextPage`? Are you storing it in an array? A class-level variable?

Comment: @DonMag, yes - neighbouring pages are stored in a class-level array, which are then provided as the DataSource.  The problem is `UIPageViewController` doesn't even _call_ the DataSouce for the first page turn ahead of time - and so why I would like these pages as ready-to-go as possible, so the actual page turn has little further work.